# Why it shows error While updating an array using jq

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

My JSON file (temp.json):

```
{
    "first": {
        "second": [
            {
                "third": [
                    "1000",
                    "1001"
                ],
                "fourth": "Don'tWantToChange"
            },
            {
                "third": [
                    "1000",
                    "1001",
                    "1002"
                ],
                "fourth": "WantToChange"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to select an item from array and update as below

```
{
    "first": {
        "second": [
            {
                "third": [
                    "1000",
                    "1001"
                ],
                "fourth": "Don'tWantToChange"
            },
            {
                "third": [
                    "1000",
                    "1001",
                    "1002"
                ],
                "fourth": "changed"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is my code:

```
jq '(.first | .second[] | select(.third | index("1002")) | .fourth) |= "changed"' temp.json
```

It works on Online JQ Playgrounds perfectly

But in the terminal, it shows Error:

```
jq: error (at temp.json:13): Invalid path expression near attempt to access element "fourth" of {"third":["1000","1001","1...
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What jq version do you have?

Comment: jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe

Comment: This works without error for me using jq 1.6.

Comment: Can you upgrade?

Comment: Don't have 1.5 to test, but can you try: `.first.second |= map(if .third | index("1002") then .fourth = "change" else . end)`

Comment: @glennjackman  using ubuntu 18 , can't upgrade

Comment: The posted query works using the official jq 1.5 (verified using Mac OS X).

Comment: Note that jq is just a single executable. You can [download the v1.6 executable](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/download/) and store it somewhere in your PATH.

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, Using jq 1.6 executable file works either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe (as packaged with certain releases of Debain and Ubuntu) had issues with inferring types from a pipelined `select` filter. In this case, `index` provides `null` if the value was not found, or a number (the actual index) if it was, but `select` requires a boolean result in its body.

Workaround: Wrap the body in parens, and compare its result against `null` to get a boolean:

```bash
(.first | .second[] | select((.third | index("1002")) != null) | .fourth) = "changed"
```

Solution: Upgrade to jq 1.6. It was released in 2018.

Note: With the given sample, neither version requires the update operator `|=`. Just use `=` to assign a static value.

Comment: thanks to @jqurious, his solution works either `.first.second |= map(if .third | index("1002") then .fourth = "change" else . end)`

Comment: @pmf - I had no problem using jq 1.5.  In any case, I'm puzzled by your characterization of `select`.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: @peak It might be OS-specific (in particular: compared to your experiences on Mac OS), but on older Debian machines I ran into issues of this kind more than just once (double-checked this very issue on Debian 10 Buster using its packaged jq 1.5-1-a5b5cbe). They all boiled down to somewhat complex `select` filters with non-boolean results. Since these filters looked alright, and indeed did work on rolling Arch machines using packaged jq-1.6, I instantly blamed the different versions. But if you can't reproduce this one with jq 1.5 on Mac OS, then OS-specific libraries etc might also be a cause.

Comment: @pmf - `git blame` tells me that `def select(f):` has been around since 2015 and that it's just implemented using `if...then...else...end`: 143e8dc5 .... 2015-10-17 23:24:13 -0700   4) def select(f): if f then . else empty end;

Comment: @peak Then it's all the more interesting why the `if`-based approach [propsed by jqurious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76583318/why-it-shows-error-while-updating-an-array-using-jq/76584088?noredirect=1#comment135027574_76583318) indeed does work with jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe on both OP's Ubuntu and my Debian machine (as does OP's original approach using jq-1.6 on both machines).